# "withInitial" vs "InitialValue" In threadLocal

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, thread-local, inheritable-thread-local

I am bit confused between **initialValue** vs **withInital** method for threadLocal.

Consider a situation, I have data in parent thread, and I am using `InheritableThreadLocal`.

```
public class Parent extends Thread {
public static ThreadLocal<String> data = new InheritableThreadLocal<String>() {
    @Override
    protected String initialValue() {
        return "temp";
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Parent().start();
}

public void run() {
    data.set("parent data");
    System.out.println("Parent Thread Value :" + data.get());
    new ChildThread().start();
}

class ChildThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Child Thread Value :" + Parent.data.get());
    }
}
}
```

Output:

```
Parent Thread Value : parent data
Child Thread Value : parent data
```

I am creating thread in parent, and calling child thread. The child is inheriting data from parent thread.

Now if I initialize variable `data` (In line 2) like this:

```
public static ThreadLocal<String> data =InheritableThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> "temp");
```

I get the following output:

```
Parent Thread Value :parent data
Child Thread Value :temp
```

I am not sure why its happening. I read oracle's document, but didn't get something useful.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html#withInitial-java.util.function.Supplier-
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html#initialValue--

I wonder how can I achieve the same output with `withInitial` instead of using `initialValue`?

Comment: `withInitial` will return a `ThreadLocal` as it is a factory method on `ThreadLocal` not on `InheritableThreadLocal`. However it is visible from `InheritableThreadLocal` because that extends `ThreadLocal`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`withInitial` does not create an `InheritableThreadLocal`. It only creates a regular `ThreadLocal`, which is why you see `temp` in the output.

`withInitial` is a static method, so it can't be overridden by `InheritableThreadLocal` to do something different instead, like returning an `InheritableThreadLocal`.

So you can't do the same thing, but with `withInitial`, because it doesn't return the type of object you need.

Comment: Of course, `InheritableThreadLocal` could declare its own `withInitial` method. It just doesn’t. Most likely, because it makes little sense to provide a factory for an inheritable thread local variable that never inherits a value.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answer, `withInitial` is defined in `ThreadLocal` and returns an object of a type `SuppliedThreadLocal` that extends `ThreadLocal` and not `InheritableThreadLocal`. Since such a static factory method is not defined (yet?) in the JDK, you can create your own inheritable utility version:

```
static final class SuppliedInheritableThreadLocal<T> extends InheritableThreadLocal<T> {

    private final Supplier<? extends T> supplier;

    SuppliedInheritableThreadLocal(Supplier<? extends T> supplier) {
        this.supplier = Objects.requireNonNull(supplier);
    }

    @Override
    protected T initialValue() {
        return supplier.get();
    }

    public static <S> ThreadLocal<S> withInitial(Supplier<? extends S> supplier) {
        return new SuppliedInheritableThreadLocal<>(supplier);
    }
}

public static ThreadLocal<String> data = SuppliedInheritableThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> "temp");
```